# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

If I have a real $n \times n$ matrix with entries $a_{ij}=\delta_{ij}-p_ip_j$ where $p$ is an $n$-vector, how can I find the eigenvalues and the corresponding eigenvectors of this matrix? I have done the case $n=2$ and found that the eigenvalues are $\lambda=1 $ or $=1-|p|^2$.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that your matrix can be written as $I-pp^T$?

Comment: Yes,it is correct

Comment: Ok, then you have $I-  \vert p \vert  ^2 (pp^T/ {\vert p \vert} ^2)$ where matrix in the brackets is a projection matrix of the form $nn^T$ with norm of $n$  equal $1$ as pointed in the answer below.

Comment: Generally the projection matrix $nn^T$ has eignevalues only $0$ and $1$, they are really transformed by polynomial formula of your new matrix to $1$ and $1-{\vert p \vert}^2$.. if you have other similar matrix obtained with polynomial formula from more elementary symmetric matrix you can obtain   new eigenvalues with the use of this polynomial formula as in this case. Note that polynomial of symmetric matrix is always also symmetric..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that this matrix looks a little bit like a projector. Every vector orthogonal to $p_i$ is unchanged, whilst $p_i$ itself is rescaled by $1-|p|^2$. If $|p|=1$ this would be a legitimate projection matrix.

The eigenvectors are hence $p_i$, with eigenvalue $1-|p|^2$, as well as all vectors in the $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace orthogonal to $p_i$, with eigenvalue $1$.

Comment: Are there some methods to deal with a more general symmetric matrix?

Comment: I'm not sure. It depends on how general you want to get.

Comment: @mnmn1993 so my answer to this part of the question could be as mentioned earlier, sometimes we can express the symmetric matrix as a polynomial of the more elementary in form symmetric matrix. In this case we can use polynomial formula also for calculating eigenvalues of more complicated matrix from eigenvalues of this elementary matrix.. additionally ..polynomials of a matrix have the same eigenvectors as the initial matrix..

Comment: You mean that symmetric matrix can be expressed as a polynomial of some projection matrix?

Comment: @mnmn1993 Not always, but sometimes (as in your example) this can be done..